# Циклы for в С

Tags: c

Если можно объясните как работает данный цикл (что за чем  в нем происходит):

```
for ( int i = 1; i <= total; i++ ) {
    for ( int j = 1; j < i; j++ ) {
        printf("%d ", j);
    }
    printf("%d\n", i);
}
```

В целом задача выглядит так:

```
include <stdio.h>

int main() {

int total;

scanf("%d", &total);

for ( int i = 1; i <= total; i++ ) {
    for ( int j = 1; j < i; j++ ) {
        printf("%d ", j);
    }
    printf("%d\n", i);
}
return 0;

}
```

Пример ввода

```
3
```

Пример вывода

```
1

1 2

1 2 3
```

Answer (score 1):

У нас два цикла, причем один вложенный. В первом изменяется i до total, к примеру от 1 до 10. Во вложенном цикле изменяется j, но уже до j<i, к примеру если текущее значение i равно 5, то j будет изменятся от 1 до 4. Внутри вложенного цикла у нас происходит вывод текущего значения j, причем вывод идет в одну строку через пробел. По окончанию вложенного цикла происходит переход на другую строку `\n` (у вас там ошибка), и вывод текущего значения i.

К примеру, получается вот такой "треугольник", если total=4:

1

2 1

3 1 2

4 1 2 3

Comment: n - это не у @Игорь91 ошибка, это у Хэшкода форматер бэкслеши жрет.

Comment: Аааа ну Ок!)

Comment: @avp, если правильно редактировать, то ничего не сжирается

Comment: Безусловно, можно набрать правильную для отображения на экране последовательность символов. 

Но, может быть правильным решением является отображать то, что набрано, а не заниматься самодеятельным форматированием ?